# Loading ajax data and return button didn't get back the ajax content

Tags: jquery, ajax

I created a website with ajax content my website is http://www.mr-parts.com, i clicked to a product page link in my listing product but when i tried to go back by retrun button after ajax load i don't get the last ajax content, is there a good solution to handle this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: need little more than just that to help you

Comment: i edited my question, hope that is more clear now

Answer (score 1):

I think people need to think outside the box sometimes (aimed at commenter's and down-voters).

I've achieved this before by using HTML5's push state.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

On your AJAX call you manipulate the URL in the browser and add an entry to the browser history.

So lets say for example you changed the URL from http://www.mr-parts.com to http://www.mr-parts.com?ajaxcallstate=1, you could then do a check against ajaxcallstate=1 in the querystring on page load and fire off the ajax call required.

This will only work in latest browsers however as it is HTML 5 technology